# Display name with comma is split up in SharePoint People Picker

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server, active-directory, people-picker

I am running into an issue in SharePoint 2007 where I have user profiles that contain a display name with the value "[last name], [first name]".
In SharePoint when using the people picker control allowing multiple names, I can find or enter the user by using the display name property including the comma and save the record.

When I go back to edit the record, the user is split up with the comma removed as if it is being used to separate two entries.

Here is the initial entry which is fine:
[image: First entry of the user]

When you go back to edit the record, the display name is split (because the comma is being treated as a delimiter):
[image: Returning to edit the record where the name is split]

I believe the name entry is being stored correctly, but that when you edit the record, the name is being split at the comma. I believe this can be fixed by configuration, but I am not sure which settings should be adjusted. I looked at the people picker admin configuration options and didn't see anything that would seem to impact this.
Unfortunately I don't think it will be possible to permanently strip the commas for the display name property unless we are absolutely forced.

What settings should I configure? Is there anything specifically that I should adjust to prevent the name getting split up?

Comment: Looks like you found a new MOSS 2007 "feature"

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this is behavior based on on custom rendering of the control in our solution. It's not a general SharePoint issue after all. I needed to fix the code behind in C#. Names are added using a comma delimited string in the code behind which is triggering the behavior.